# Get Smarty-formatted data from PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, smarty, prestashop

My PHP script, that I call via XMLHttpRequest, executes a query and checks a condition, then outputs a HTML snippet with some Smarty code. When I try to insert that code in a `<div>` tag, either by calling the `jQuery.html()` function or by setting the `innerHTML` property, the Smarty code is printed as it is, thus not interpreted as Smarty code. How could I solve this problem?

Relevant code:

PHP Script:

```
<?php
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "<<<SQL USERNAME>>>", "<<<SQL PASSWORD>>>", "<<<SQL DATABASE>>>");
        $id = $_GET["idmf"];
        $cat = $mysqli->query("<<<SQL QUERY>>>")->fetch_assoc()["category"];
        if ($cat == $_GET["cat"])
            echo 'blahblah';
?>
```

TPL file:

```
{foreach from=$manufacturers item=manufacturer name=manufacturers}
    <div id="mffilter_{$manufacturer.id_manufacturer}"></div>
    <script>

        var xhttpf;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xhttpf = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xhttpf = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttpf.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            {
                document.getElementById("mffilter_{$manufacturer.id_manufacturer}").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttpf.open("GET", "<<<ENDPOINT>>>.php?cat=food&idmf={$manufacturer.id_manufacturer}", true);
        xhttpf.send();

    </script>
```

Comment: Smarty doesn't work that way. You need to parse the desired html in php script with smarty before echoing. Also if you're using Prestashop use its controllers and its db access methods for ajax calls.

Comment: @TheDrot Could you address me somehow please?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your TPL file code with the following code:

```
{foreach from=$manufacturers item=manufacturer name=manufacturers}
    <div id="mffilter_"{$manufacturer.id_manufacturer}></div>
    <script>

        var xhttpf;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xhttpf = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xhttpf = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhttpf.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            {
                document.getElementById("mffilter_"{$manufacturer.id_manufacturer}).innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttpf.open("GET", "<<<ENDPOINT>>>.php?cat=food&idmf="{$manufacturer.id_manufacturer}, true);
        xhttpf.send();

    </script>
```